# Usage of types.FunctionType with closure option

Tags: python

I am exploring dynamic creation of function objects by **FunctionType** (for learning purposes) and can't understand how to use a closure parameter.

From `help(types.FunctionType)`:

> `function(code, globals[, name[, argdefs[, closure]]])`
>
> The optional closure tuple supplies the bindings for free variables.

A simple expression works:

```
def foo():
    code = compile("print(3 + 2)", filename='FunctionType_test', mode='eval')
    new_func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "generated_function")
    return new_func

foo()()
```

How can I bind a variable from outer scope to a new function object?

```
def foo(foo_var):
    code = compile("print(foo_var + 2)", filename='FunctionType_test', mode='eval')
    new_func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "generated_function")
    return new_func

foo(3)()
```

I want to achieve the same behaviour, but by **FunctionType**:

```
def foo(foo_var):
    def bar():
        print(foo_var + 2)

    return bar

foo(3)()
```